# Can I really fish a feebas on route 2?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

According to online sources like [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Galar_Route_2#Across_the_lake), it's possible to fish a Feebas on route 2, with a 1% rate.

I tried for a while (at least 250 tries), on both fishing spots around the island in the middle of the lake, and I got nothing. I've caught other 1% pokémon and they were never this long.

I've seen other people struggling as well online, so I'm suspecting you need a condition to make it possible, like an item, a badge or something (I have all badges but haven't done the Battle Tower yet).

Should I just keep trying or do I need to do something in particular?

<sub>*This question is not "How to get a Feebas?", it's "Is it possible to fish a Feebas on route 2?".*</sub>

Comment: If there's a 1% chance to find a Pokémon, that means there's a (0.99^250) = ~8% chance that you won't have encountered it after 250 attempts which is unlikely but still possible.  Bulbapedia's sources tend to come from direct game data or published print guides, so it's unlikely to be wrong in this particular instance.

Answer (score 4):

The base spawn rates are what they are without any additional effects, and badges/Battle Tower have no impact on spawn rates at all. Certain abilities can make encounters more likely but aren't required for the encounter to be possible in the first place.

A 1% chance is simply low enough that streaks of bad luck become more likely. As Chase Sandmann said in a comment, you have about an 8% chance of not getting a 1% encounter after 250 tries. So about 1 out of every 12-13 players would have the same bad luck you had or worse, which is why you see so many other accounts of it happening. But it's the same odds as, say, not getting a 1/512 shiny after ~1300 eggs, and I've seen countless players complain about far worse dry streaks than that.

The spawn rates on Bulbapedia and other sources come directly from disassembling the game code, so unless there's a bug in the game they are correct.

Answer (score -1):

As seen in a comment under [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q1yM7KIDzio) you can place a pokémon with Storm Drain as your lead in your party (a Shellos for example).

With it it seems like every pokémon has an equal spawn chance, so Feebas is much easier to catch.

I still don't know if it's possible to catch a Feebas without it, so any information about that would be welcome. Maybe the rate is very, very low and got rounded up to 1%, I don't know where those spawn rates come from.

Comment: Storm Drain makes it more likely to encounter Water Pokémon.

Comment: @Wrigglenite I know. All 3 possible encounters are water types (magikarp, chewtle and feebas), and it's not obvious that it changes the rates completely. If you know how it works in detail please share.

Comment: That's all it does, it makes Water Pokémon spawn more often. It won't do anything if you can only find Water Pokémon in the first place.

Comment: @Wrigglenite Well, try it. I didn't get a single feebas in 2 hours of fishing. I did this and got 3 in 10 encounters. I wouldn't have written an answer if I hadn't successfully tried it.